# Error While Encrypting External Drive using BitLocker

Tags: windows, bitlocker

I have a 6TB WD External Drive - My Book Studio Edition II - with lots of our backups which i want to connect to a Windows 8.1 Pro Machine that has BitLocker enabled on it. I cannot ignore this drive from being Bitlocker enabled due to company policy. I, therefore, had to encrypt it. During encrypting it, it gave me an error after running for almost 48 hours that says:

"This disk has one or more errors. Run ChkDsk /r. If these errors persist, this may be indicative of a hardware fault. Contact the administrator of your system."

I ran chkdsk on the drive, it reported some corruption errors similar to this one:

Attribute record (128, "") from file record segment 48104 is corrupt.

and then complained saying CHKDSK cannot run on a read-only drive. The bitlocker encryption process made the external drive as read-only. I tried to run chkdsk on it by restarting the computer in safe mode, but in safe mode, the external drive is detected as "RAW" and I cannot run chkdsk on it. The drive is now 75% encrypted, and read-only. I cannot continue encryption because of the error, and the error cannot be fixed unless the drive is read-write (for it be writable, encryption has to complete).

I have these questions:

1. Based on CHKDSK command execution on the external drive (the corruption error as shown above) , is my external drive corrupt and cannot be used any longer?
2. How can it be decrypted to make it writable, so that, we can run CHKDSK to fix the corruption, if possible? I do not get any option to decrypt it either in normal windows mode or in safe mode.

Please help. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to backup the data on the drive before the device fails.  You need to do this before I can suggest any solution to your problem.

Comment: Can you please provide the solution? I would appreciate it. I have backed up some of the files which were more important than others.